# How to get Firebase Cloud Firestore data in one line that returns one value in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from a firebase cloud firestore database in one line in a Text component in react native. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
...
<Text style={styles.name}>
 {firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(post.uid).get().name}
</Text>
...
```

This code is trying to place a value in a React Native Text component by fetching a document with id "post.uid" so that the document data is returned where the value "name" is called and returns a single string. I would appreciate any help on how to do this as I am not able to figure out the solution. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can get is by using `await`

```
(await firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(post.uid).get()).data().name
```

I recommend studying the Firestore documentation on [getting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) carefully, and trying to get the value outside of your render function first.

---

**Update**

Since you're using react, I'd highly recommend taking this approach:

1. In your `componentDidMount` start loading the data.
2. Once the data is loaded call `setState()` to add it to the state.

   Combined these look like:

   ```
   componentDidMount() {
     firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(post.uid).get().then((doc) => {
       this.setState({ name: doc.data().name });
     }
   }
   ```
3. Then render the data from the state.

   ```
   <Text style={styles.name}>
    {this.state.name}
   </Text>
   ```

Also see:

- [How to update Firebase data to the React application in realtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59871401/how-to-update-firebase-data-to-the-react-application-in-realtime/59871491#59871491)

Comment: I am receiving a TypeError  that this is not a function and that it could only be called within an async funtion. How would I implement this functionality with an external funtion? If you could help me I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, but I was not able to find a solution.

Comment: I added a more idiomatic solution.