# Populate dropdown fields with firebase data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting values in console but not able to show in drop down
[See this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAffV.png)

Can anybody explain what im doing wrong here

```
        return firebase.database().ref('Users/Trainers/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
                // var childKey= childSnapshot.key;
                var childData= childSnapshot.val();
                var childEmail = childData.email;
                var childfirstName = childData.firstName;
                var childlastName = childData.lastName;
                var childTrainers = childfirstName + ' ' + childlastName + ' ' + childEmail;
            console.log(childTrainers);
            })
        })
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        this.getlist();
    }
```

State

`childTrainers: []`

And in render method,

`<Select options={this.state.childTrainers} />`

Comment: Where do you call `setState` with the updated childTrainers ?

Comment: Thats what ive done mistake.. `this.setState({ 
                    CourseName : [{label: {CName}}]
                })` If doing so, im getting error

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59871401/how-to-update-firebase-data-to-the-react-application-in-realtime/59871491#59871491 for a minimal example of how to load data from Firebase, set it to the state, and render it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the state when fetching values from firebase:

```js
return firebase.database().ref('Users/Trainers/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
    const childTrainerSnapshot = snapshot.map(childSnapshot => {
        return childfirstName + ' ' + childlastName + ' ' + childEmail
    });
    this.setState({ childTrainers: childTrainerSnapshot });
})
```

Comment: Nopes, this is not working for me